# I can't get data from firestore "Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this method the get all my documents from a given collection:

```dart
  getData() async {
    
    await databaseReference
        .collection("app").doc('usr').collection(_id).
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        return result.data();
      });
    })
}
```

What I want to get is all the documents from this collection, and not only the last. With the code above I get this when calling getData()

> Instance of 'Future < dynamic>'

What I want to get:

```dart
[{name: Victor, age: 18}, {name: Tommy, age: 40}]
```

How can I reach it?

**UPDATE**

If I run the code below...:

```dart
await databaseReference
.collection("app").doc('usr').collection(_id)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((f) => print(f.data()));
    })
```

In the console it prints all the documents but separately (First prints one, after another):

```
I/flutter (16316): {name: Victor, age: 18}
I/flutter (16316): {name: Tommy, age: 40}
```

**UPDATE 2**
If I write what @Sahil Chadha and @kovalyovi suggest, and just print the list ... :

```dart
var items = List<dynamic>();
... my code....
snapshot.docs.forEach((f) => items.add(f.data()));
return items;

//returns exactly what I want
```

... It returns exactly what I want, but if I write `return items` and in the calling do `var a = getData();`, The A value is Instance of future. How can I have the result expected?

**UPDATE 3**
I forgot the await before getData(). Now it's working:

```dart
var a = await getData();
    print(a); //my expected result

  getData() async {
    var items = List<dynamic>();
      await databaseReference
.collection("app").doc('usr').collection(_id)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((f) => items.add(f.data()));
      })
return items
}
```

Comment: You can create a empty list add all documents to that list in the for loop

Comment: Can you show your approach?

Comment: replace `forEach` with `map` in your original code. `forEach` method does not return anything. what you are looking for here is `map`.

Comment: add `toList()` after the map fuction as well

Comment: Just create an empty list on the first line of `getData()`, for example 
`var items = List<dynamic>();` and then in your `forEach` instead of `print(f.data())` do `items.add(f.data())`

Comment: salil or @kovalyovi Thank you, it's working, feel free to post your answer to I give the 'ok' and upvote. If you feel the question useful, please upvote

Comment: @armstrong I added the answer. If that answers your question, feel free to accept it and thumb it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to store the data you receive in a form of a list, you will need to initialize a list at the beginning of the method and then populate that list where you `forEach` the response. As you mentioned in the comments, I am posting an answer here for you:

```dart
getData() async {
  // initialize your list here
  var items = List<dynamic>();

  await databaseReference.collection("app").doc('usr').collection(_id).get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(
      // add data to your list
      (f) => items.add(f.data()),
    );
  });
  return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like there is no problem with the code. It will be healthier if you just model the data you get. You just did not mention that you were async where you were calling. Since it is future data, there must be a waiting event.

```
 Future<List<User>> getData() async {
   await databaseReference
    .collection("app").doc('usr').collection(_id).
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) {
       querySnapshot.docs.map((f) => 
         User.fromJson(f)).toList());
   })
  }
```

You should try two of them.

```
  List<User> loaddata=await getData();
```

--OR------

```
 var loadData;
  getData().then((result){
    List<User>=result;
   });
```

and you create the user model. It will be more revealing if you do it this way.

```
  import 'dart:convert';

  User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

 String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
   User({
     this.name,
     this.age,
  });

 String name;
 int age;

 factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    name: json["name"],
    age: json["age"],
 );

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "age": age,
  };
 }
```

If there is a problem in the code, you are calling the getData method in the build widget. So you have to call it from initstate.

Comment: I edited the answer. If you are still in trouble you can give an anydesk id. I can help you. Or you need to send the entire code page.